# Gaussian like non exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Lets say I have a probability distribution $f(x) \propto a^{-\lambda x^2}$, where $a$ is any real number not necesarily equal to $e$. What do we call such a distribution? Have such distributions discussed in any detail in literature ? If $a<e$, can we call such a distribution as heavy-tailed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $a > 1$, we call it Gaussian.  $a^{-\lambda x^2} = e^{-\beta x^2}$ where $\beta = \lambda \ln(a)$.  If $ a \le 1$, it's not a probability distribution.